# Importing same file multiple times in different files?

Tags: stylus

Eg: I want to import a file called `@import 's-grid-settings'` in multiple different stylus files. Is this a bad idea?

Answer (score 2):

It depends :)

Stylus have two ways of “importing” other stylus documents: via `@import` and via `@require`.

The difference is that `@import` would import the file each time, while `@require` would do this only once.

`@require` this way could be useful to share the settings and/or some common stuff like placeholders etc. between multiple stylus files in a such way those files could be either compiled each by itself or as a bundle. If the `@import` was used in this case, it would include all its stuff every time it was called, while `@require` would do this only once at the first call.

So, the answer to your question would depend on what is there inside your file.